# How to resolve connection issues with plotly and dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

[image]

imports I am using..

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
```

Comment: Have you tried using a different port to 8050?

Comment: Yes, almost all the ports I have tried do not work. Is there a way to create a new port dedicated for this ? 8050 is used by python and I cannot kill that.